# Database mirroring option not available in sql server management studio 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-mirroring

I want to do database mirroring in sql server management studio 2008. I went through many tutorials and in those tutorials there is a option for doing mirroring in ssms 2008. But in my ssms mirroring option is not present. Could somebody please tell me how to enable mirroring in ssms 2008. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your version of sql server : Express, Standard, Enterprise ? Express edition does not support mirroring

Comment: What edition do you have? The cheaper editions don't have full support: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28SQL.100%29.aspx

Comment: Yes it's express. Now what's the solution. I have to install the Enterprise or Standard version?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here a list of sql server editions and high availability features supported by each edition.

[image]

For more details Visit here [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)

Looking at this chart the next available option for you seems to be the Standard Edition, it means spending a few quid. but the good thing is you can use your free express edition as witness server if your planning to have an auto failover which requires you to have a witness server in place.

Comment: Thanks @Muhammed Ali. You mean to say I can use that witness server for retrieving data in case of failover?

Comment: @Paul no when you want an auto failover in case of principal server is gone down you will need a witness server there other than your Principal server and the Mirror Server, Witness Servers monitors the mirroring session and sole purpose of a witness server is to trigger the failover when the Principal server goes down.

Comment: If you do not have a witness server than you cannot have an auto failover and in case of principal server goes down you have to manually failover to mirror server and bring it online.

Comment: Okay.So I have to download sql server management studio standard edition for mirroring?

Comment: @Paul yes and the bad news is its not free you will need to pay a decent amount for that :)